# How to get time string to Time in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, time

I have insert time in form of string in oracle VARCHAR2 column.   But when I try to retrieve it in form of time it's not giving me right time, it's only giving me a date which I have not saved.

```
INSERT INTO table1
    (timestr) Select substr(numtodsinterval(MAX(date1)-MIN(date2),'day'),
12,8)  from table2 where ....; // stored timestr column value: 00:00:00
```

Retrieve ...

```
select TO_DATE(timestr,'hh24:mi:ss') from table1;
```

... is only giving `10/01/2015`

Answer (score 2):

You should use to_char to see the time

```
 select to_char(timestr,'hh24:mi:ss') from table1;
```

Comment: not the answer to this question, but the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

That might be because of your client setting. If you are using SQL Developer, then go to `Tools->Preference->Database->NLS` and change setting to view timestamp also.

If you are using SQLPlus, the change `nls_date_format` or see below solution.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/312115?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle there is no concept of a TIME datatype. There are only DATE and TIMESTAMP, both of which comprise date and time elements.

Your retrieval casts your time column to a DATE: `TO_DATE(timestr,'hh24:mi:ss')`.  Oracle does what we ask it to do, so it displays a date. As there is no date element in `timestr` it assigns one for us: today's date.

You are only seeing `10/01/2015` because your client's NLS settings are configured to display only the date element. Change the setting to show the time element, in the client or by altering the session as here:

```
SQL> select to_date('10:08:23', 'hh24:mi:ss') ts from dual
  2  /

TS
---------
01-OCT-15

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('10:08:23', 'hh24:mi:ss') ts from dual
  2  /

TS
--------------------
01-OCT-2015 10:08:23

SQL>
```

If you only want to see the time you can change the NLS settings ...

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='HH24:MI:SS' 
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('10:08:23', 'hh24:mi:ss') ts from dual
  2  /

TS
--------
10:08:23

SQL>
```

...but that will get annoying ....

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual
  2  /

SYSDATE
--------
23:59:52

SQL>
```

So why not just display the column as a string all without casting to a DATE?

```
select timestr from table1;
```